# PHP - Change Code To Suite Previous Setup

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently using the following code as my MySQL login

```
<?php
    $database="";
    $mysql_user = "";
    $mysql_password = ""; 
    $mysql_host = "";
    $mysql_table_prefix = "";

    $success = mysql_pconnect ($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
    if (!$success)
        die ("<b>Cannot connect to database, check if username, password and host are correct.</b>");
    $success = mysql_select_db ($database);
    if (!$success) {
        print "<b>Cannot choose database, check if database name is correct.";
        die();
    }
?>
```

And i'm trying to intergrate an open source script to use the same login however it uses the following:

```
define("DB_HOST", "");
define("DB_NAME", "");
define("DB_USER", "");
define("DB_PASS", "");
```

Is there a way I change the 2nd script to use the details as the same as the first one so I don't need 2 databases or repeativily enter the login details twice?

I'm hoping there is some find and replace solution!

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_` functions as a start, they are deprecated. Start using PDO, it is much better and much safer

Comment: Do you mean `mysql_pconnect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);`?

Comment: If all those are empty strings, how can a connection to the database succeed?

Comment: @arkascha Why on earth would I like to share my SQL login information publically? Secuirty issue maybe why I remove the information?

Comment: Certainly I understand that you don't want to post your credentials. But don't you think it would have made sense to drop a note about the fact that you changed that code you did post?

Comment: @arkascha Maybe some people don't have common sense into thinking someone won't post there sensitive server information on a online forum for security exploiters.

Comment: @ShaquilleRay: that creative use of grammar probably is the most successful way to make sure no one understands what you are trying to say... Anyway, for the future: please make sure that a) you tell people that you modified the example you posted and b) put in some neutral placeholders like `<mypass>`. Then things are more clear for everyone. Thanks!